# I need to delete all non php files from a linux server or download them

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have thousands of files, maybe hundreds of thousands of files on a Linux Server and they are in directories, and sub directories -

The files are all located in /home/sas/httpdocs -

I want to get a copy of the entire directory with just the php files, but preserving the same directory structure -

I have two options:

either remove ALL of the non php files, then tarball it up and download it -

Or simply extract only all of the php files in a new directory but keeping the same directory structure -

Any ideas on how to do this?

Sas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will copy only `php` files into a separate dir

```
cd /home/sas/httpdocs
tar -cf - `find . -name "*.php" -print` | ( cd /destination_dir && tar xBf - )
```

Ther is another method of deleting non-php files. Here is it, detailed elegantly

https://superuser.com/questions/168130/unix-delete-files-and-folders-excluding-pattern

Comment: Will it keep the same directory structure?

Comment: Yup. It will keep the same dir structure.

Comment: so if I wanted the tar to go up one folder I would do it like this? ---

Comment: tar -cf - `find . -name "*.php" -print` | ( cd /home/sas/files.tar && tar xBf - )

Comment: Oh i get it, we are not actually tarring the files into a single tar, we are just making a directory - ill go ahead and try this -

Comment: How long mitght it take to run its been running for a while now, and I do not see any files copied over to the new directory yet -

Comment: It should go on at a pretty decent speed. But I speculate you are using some wrong command. Cos in one of your command I see you are using `/home/sas/files.tar`. It should be just `/home/sas/files` . NO tar there. Also there are `` around `find` command which you might be missing

Comment: It worked for me with a basic sample of 16 files in 2 tier dir structure... (+1) Thanks

Comment: I forgot about it and lo and behold it was actually complete, it worked, thanks! -

Comment: If you have thousand of files, giving the files as argument to tar could break !  You could use `find . -name "*.php" -print | tar -T - ...`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `rsync` could be an option:

```
rsync -av --include "*/" --include "*.php" --exclude "*" /home/sas/httpdocs/. /copy/dir/
```

Comment: How long will this take? I ran the earlier tar command, and it is still running - RSYNC might at least show up a little faster? Do you know - I have over 100k files in one or two directories maybe -

Comment: rsync should be faster because no need to tar & untar all files. rsync do the copy directly.

Comment: The `tar` method uses a direct pass-through from the *input tar* to the *output tar*; The only "extra" overhead is in gathering paths and directory structure info and then it sends the files via the pipe to the output tar... This is pretty much what `rsync` would do in this situation ("this" meaning it can't utilize its ability to only write sections of modified data) ... So I think it would be pretty much even keel here... `rsync` would be fine too ... (+1) ...

Answer (score 0):

To delete the file not ending by `.php`:

```
find /dir -type f ! -name "*.php" -print
```

When you are happy with the output, replace the `-print` by `-delete`.